# How do I remove white space between div's in HTML before appending text to the title between the div's

Tags: jquery, append, trim

I feel like the answer falls with the .trim tool in jquery but I'm not sure how to execute on it.

I have an html document that looks like this

```
<div class='title'>
Title
</div>
```

When I append a description to the title it still looks great

```
$( ".title" ).append( " - Description" );
```

Title - Description

The problem is when I pass the text to the url I get

interest=Title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Description

When I want to retrieve the value for 'interest' I have a ton of garbage.  Can someone help me resolve my issue.

Thank You

Comment: How are you getting the text?

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the duplicate spaces with a regular expression. I am assuming you are using text() to get the content.

```
var str = $( ".title" ).text().replace(/\s+/g," ");
```

jQuery's trim is only going to clean up the whitespace on the ends. You may want to use that here too.

```
var txt = $( ".title" ).text()
var str = $.trim(txt.replace(/\s+/g," "));
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be the use of trim: (you said you do not know exactly how to use);

```
var text = $(".title").text().trim();
$(".title").text(text + " - Description");
```